# Correct way to implement sub id?

Tags: postgresql, race-condition

Suppose I have a table of the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id SERIAL,
  type VARCHAR(10),
  sub_id INTEGER,
  UNIQUE (type, sub_id)
)
```

where I want the "sub_id" column to be a counter within a specific "type". Example:

```
id  |  type  | sub_id
---------------------
1   |  'foo' | 1
--------------------
2   |  'foo' | 2
--------------------
3   |  'foo' | 3
--------------------
4   |  'bar' | 1
--------------------
5   |  'bar' | 2
```

To insert a new row I thought of using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO test(type,sub_id)
SELECT 'foo', MAX(sub_id)+1
FROM test
WHERE type='foo'
```

But then I discovered that this query is vulnerable to race conditions.
What is a proper way to keep sub counters within types?

Comment: really, there is no proper way that doesn't involve table locking, you can get something that almost works by using sequences, but you already have something that almost works.  What is supposed to  happen when rows are deleted?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of possible types are known in advance, I would suggest using dedicated sequences:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_sub_id;
CREATE SEQUENCE bar_sub_id;
```

I'm not sure about your actual requirements, but another option would be of course not to actually store the `sub_id`, but to calculate it wherever you need to consume it:

```
SELECT id, type, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id) sub_id
FROM test
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's essential to have the sub_ids in the table and numbered sequentially with no gaps then using sequences isn't going to do it,
because sequences can have gaps. So, you're going to have to lock the entire table and then use your original approach.

```
BEGIN Transaction;
LOCK TABLE test;
INSERT INTO test(type,sub_id)
SELECT 'foo', MAX(sub_id)+1
FROM test
WHERE type='foo';
COMMIT;
```

If gaps are allowed just use the `id` column.

If it's just for "looks" the the window query proposed by Lukas Eder looks good to me too:

```
SELECT id, type, 
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id) AS sub_id 
FROM test
```